# How can I check if two plots have the same shape in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shapes

I have a dataset with variables x, y1 and y2.

If I plot(x,y1) and plot(x,y2) the plots look almost the same, but I would like to measure how much they are alike. Is there a function or measurement for it? Is this possible in R? Only the shape of the plot matters.

EDIT for clarification:

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
y1<-c(10,20,30,40,50)
y2<-c(101,201,301,401,501)
```

Now when you plot(x,y1) and plot(x,y2) these plots have the almost the same shape, just a scale factor makes for the biggest difference. Is there a way to test how closely related both plot shapes are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `plot(x,y1)` is similar in shape to `plot(x,y2)`, then `y1` and `y2` should be similar to each other. You can compute the [correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) between them.

The correlation goes from +1 (both plots are the same) to -1 (they are reversed). If it is 0, it means there is no relationship.

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(0) # seed to random number generation, to reproduce examples

x <- runif(50)
y1 <- x^2 + runif(50,-.1,.1)
y2 <- x^2 + runif(50,-.1,.1)
y3 <- runif(50) # unrelated to x

par(mfrow=c(2,3))
plot(x,y1)
plot(x,y2)
plot(y1,y2)
plot(x,y3)
plot(y1,y3)
plot(y2,y3)

# Compute correlations
cor(y1,y2)
# 0.9642746 <- high correlation
cor(y1, y3)
# -0.05674353 <- like random!
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide us with a sample of your data, and/or the two plots you are trying to compare? The first things that come to mind are the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (which can be used to compare two distributions) and dynamic derivative time warping (which can be used to compare two time series). Both are doable in R (ks.test and the dtw package).

Comment: I added some clarification. Hopefully it's possible

Comment: Comparing the distributions doesn't work because you lose the order. `plot(x,y1)` is different from `plot(x,rev(y1))`, but their distributions are the same.